# c# pass by value

Tags: c#

I am just wondering to take the following example:

```
public void main()
{

   int x = 1;

   Foo(x);
}

public void Foo(int y)
{
    y = 5;
}
```

We know that C# arguments are passed by value for value types. Does this mean in the above example, that I have 2 copies on the stack, one for x and one for y?

Comment: Sorry for being picky but the above code will not compile in the first case :p

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there will be two independent variables on the stack. They will be in two different stack frames, too - one for `main` and one for `foo` (assuming no inlining). When `Foo` returns, the value of `x` will still be 1, not 5.

In fact, arguments are *always* passed by value by default in C#, both for reference types and value types. The only difference is that for reference types, the argument value *is* a reference - not the object itself.

See my [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/%7Eskeet/csharp/parameters.html) for a lot more detail on this.

Note that the actual behaviour of what goes on the stack is an [implementation detail](https://ericlippert.com/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/): the C# compiler has to make sure that a program behaves as defined in the specification, but that doesn't mandate stack or heap behaviour. So `x` *does* have to have the value of 1 at the end of your code, but a valid C# compiler *could* have put both `x` and `y` on the heap.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I feel star-struck, the great Jon Skeet. Cant wait for your upcoming book. Question on in-lining, how does the compiler decide whether to inline a method call or not?

Comment: Or they could go on neither the stack nor the heap; it would be entirely reasonable to (1) generate code that puts this in registers, or (2) generate *no code at all* since this code does nothing and has no side effects, and that can be determined at jit time.

Comment: @ash2010: The C# compiler does not inline anything. The JIT compiler does the inlining, and in CLR v4, it will tell you when it decided to do inlining! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/05/11/jit-etw-tracing-in-net-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You understand correctly - the value for `x` will be put on the stack in the stack frame for the `main` function, and the value for `y` will be placed on the stack in the stack frame  for `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

For more details you also need to understand how value parameters are passed.
The reason that y in Foo is not affecting x in Main is that they are in different stack frames. More details on passing value type parameters are [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t0za5es%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I can't say I'm keen on that page. For example, it calls out value types specifically, and says: "Therefore, passing a value-type variable to a method means passing a copy of the variable to the method." That's true for reference types too. (Well, assuming it means a copy of the variable's *value* - it's certainly not copying the variable itself.) It's just that for a reference type variable, the value is a reference. That value is still copied by default...